# Passing data as intent result

Tags: android

I create intent to `AddDeviceActivity` from `MainActivity`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddDeviceActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CHECK);
```

And expecting to get result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHECK) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)

                if ( data.getData() !=null ) {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("got result " + data.getData().toString());
                } else
                {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("got null data " );
                }

    }
}
```

`AddDeviceActivity`  puts some data:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    getIntent().putExtra("PTREFENCE_CHANGED", "fffff");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());

}
```

When `AddDeviceActivity` finishes I receive call to `onActivityResult`, but `data.getData()` returns `null`.

How to retrieve data from Intent?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
getIntent().putExtra("PTREFENCE_CHANGED", "fffff");
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent().putExtra("PTREFENCE_CHANGED", "fffff");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

You should not rely on whatever is backing that getIntent method, it may not update the underlying object the way you think it does, i.e. getIntent could create a copy each time `get` is called.

---

You could also directly get your String as the first test (instead of using `getData()`.

```
String result = data.getStringExtra("PTREFENCE_CHANGED")
Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Got: " +result);
```

---

Lastly, you might want to check your PreferenceChanged method is being called, by using some more logs.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("On Preference Changed. Setting Result OK.");
    Intent intent = getIntent().putExtra("PTREFENCE_CHANGED", "fffff");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

Comment: @Vico If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers